# How to enable altbeacon android library forground service only if entered beacon region?

Tags: service, ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I'm using **altbeacon** android library for beacon detection in my app. It runs **foreground services** as a feature by default, but I only want to run foreground services when I enter a **beacon region** or when one beacon is detected. This problem does not appear to be documented anywhere. Would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AndroidBeaconLibrary 2.19+, autobind APIs can be used to easily switch to using a foreground service after a detection.

The basic steps are:

1. In a **custom Application class**, call `beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)` in the `onCreate()` method.  This sets up initial beacon detections using scheduled jobs.
2. When you get a callback to `didEnterRegion()` you will need to call `beaconManager.stopMonitoring(...)` and `beaconManager.stopRanging(...)` for all monitored and ranged regions.
3. After step 2, configure the library for a foreground service as shown [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library-reference-kotlin/blob/7ec3e0d6e70be2d722f799bd823c3645c4e452bb/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/BeaconReferenceApplication.kt#L87)
4. Again start monitoring/ranging any desired regions.

**Be careful with the above approach**, as standard [Android will block starting a foreground service from the background in Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/foreground-services) in some cases.  In addition, some non-standard OEMs already do this on earlier Android versions.

In general, the recommended practice is to set up the foreground service only if (a) the app is in the foreground or (b) you know the user has recently interacted with your app's UI.  If Android blocks your app from starting the foreground service, starting monitoring/ranging from the background with a foreground service configured will cause your app to crash.  Because the conditions that may cause this are complex and hard to predict, this technique may lead to unexpected crashes and related bugs.

One alternative to the above is to use the new [IntentScanStrategy](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/1030) introduced in the library, which allows faster background scanning without the need for a foreground service.

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung can you please clear my confusion, what I understand is setting `setIntentScanningStrategyEnabled` to `true` will allow my application to get notified about monitoring event like enter and exit, and no need to define a service in manifest, without the need of an explicit foreground service, right?

Points to note
- Android 11
- not using the setforegroundservice method
- not starting any foreground service
But I only get `MonitorNotifier` when app is in foreground, rare to none when app is removed from overview screen.

Comment: Please post a new question with additional details including your test phone make and model.

Comment: Currently I am exploring behavior with foreground service, will post a new question afterwards. The device is [POCO M2 by XIAOMI](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_poco_m2_reloaded-10867.php). As it is Xiaomi it might be the case of Forked OEM restriction. But I am more concerned about Android 11 restriction.